# How to get an entry's dependencies array in Webpack?

Tags: webpack

For example, I have `webpack.config.js` as follows:

```
module.exports = {
    entry: {
        one: './one.js',
        two: './two.js',
    },
    plugins: [
        new webpack.CommonsChunkPlugin({}),
    ],
}
```

If `one` and `two` have common dependencies, this will emit three assets:

- one.js
- two.js
- vendor.js

I want to know how to get the dependencies array for entries, for example, for entry `one`, the dependencies array is `one.js` and `vendor.js`.

Thanks!